# Add EditText by clicking on button

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-edittext

Hi I want to add more text fields dynamically by button as on mobile, if we are adding contact information, here we can add dynamic text fields.!

[image]

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `EditText` object and add into your `Layout`. Like

```
EditText edt=new EditText(context);
```

then add into your `View` like

```
main_layout.addView(edt);
```

and go to this for more information [How to add components dynamically?](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/)

Comment: now I want to get all values from editTexts, so how can I use get them..? please suggest me..thank you.

Comment: @Ankit Get value like `String str=edt.getText().toString();`

Comment: No I mean to say that if I am adding 3 fields so how can I get all different values...?

Comment: @Mr. M D, what happen..?

Comment: I want to implement this can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73090637/6854117)?

Answer (score 0):

on the click of a button create an Edit text in your activity. and add it to your layout

example:-

```
EditText t = new EditText(myContext);
t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
layout.addView(t);
```

Comment: Now how can I got values from all fields...? Suppose I added 3 fields, so how can I get all values..?

Comment: attach id to each Edit text and then get the value through that id, same as you get from xml layout.

Comment: example:- edttext.setId(your id);

Comment: ok but please tell me how can I assign different id to each editText, as I am creating it dynamically..?
Please tell me...

Comment: I want to implement this can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73090637/6854117)?